# AS3 AutoScroll Speed Control

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, scroll, cs4

I am trying to get a menu that has videos that I will scroll through at a certain speed. Right now I have 30FPS which I have tried to lower which doesn't' help. Can anyone please help me control the speed of the auto scroll? Below is the code. I appreciate any help.

```
 package zoom
{

import flash.display.*;
import flash.media.*;
import flash.events.*;
import flash.ui.Mouse;
//importing classes
import flash.text.TextField;
import flash.text.TextFieldAutoSize;
import flash.text.TextFormat;
import flash.text.TextFormatAlign;
import flash.text.AntiAliasType;
import flash.filters.*;
import flash.net.*;
import flash.utils.*;
import flash.geom.*;
import flash.ui.*;
import caurina.transitions.*;
import caurina.transitions.properties.FilterShortcuts;
import caurina.transitions.properties.DisplayShortcuts;

import flash.system.Capabilities;



public class Scroller extends MovieClip
{

    private var source:DisplayObject = null;

    private var i:int = 0; //for the 'for' instruction
    private var buttonPos:int = 0;
    private var buttonCon:MovieClip = new MovieClip();

    private var w:int = 0;
    private var h:int = 0;
    private var dir:String = ""
    private var scrollbar:String = "";

    private var viewIndex:int = 0;
    private var errorOffset:int = 30;
    public var scrollOffset:int = 0;
    private var blurScroll:String = "on";//choose on/off if you want blur scroll

    private var mouseDown:Boolean = false;
    private var scrollIndex:int = 0;
    private var scrollbar_mc:MovieClip;
    public var gradientMask:String = "on";
    public var bg:Sprite = new Sprite();
    public var maskSize:int = 15;
    public var isScroll:Boolean = true;
    public function Scroller()
    {
        this.name = "scroller";
    }
    public function feedvars(psource:DisplayObject,pw:int,ph:int,pdir:String = "ver",pscrollbar:String = "off")
    {

        w = pw;
        h = ph;
        dir = pdir;
        scrollbar = pscrollbar;
        DisplayShortcuts.init(); 

        FilterShortcuts.init();

        source = psource;

        //we set up the mask



        addChild(source);
        trace('Scroller.as: sh: ' + source.height);

        if (Capabilities.screenResolutionX < 1200)
        blurScroll = "off";
        trace("Scroller.as: sc" + scrollbar);
        if (scrollbar == "on")
        {

            addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_WHEEL, handleMouseWheel);
            if (dir == "ver")
            {
                if (h < source.height)
                {
                vscrollbar_mc.x = w;
                vscrollbar_mc.bg_mc.height = h;
                scrollbar_mc = vscrollbar_mc;

                hscrollbar_mc.visible = false;
                setChildIndex(vscrollbar_mc, numChildren - 1);
                }
                else
                isScroll = false;
            }
            else
            {
                if (w < source.width)
                {
                hscrollbar_mc.y = h;
                hscrollbar_mc.bg_mc.width = w;
                scrollbar_mc = hscrollbar_mc;

                vscrollbar_mc.visible = false;
                setChildIndex(hscrollbar_mc, numChildren - 1);
                }
                else
                isScroll = false;
            }
            if(scrollbar_mc!=null){
            scrollbar_mc.buttonMode = true;
                scrollbar_mc.mouseChildren = false;
            scrollbar_mc.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, handleScrollbarMouse,false,0,true);}
                addEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, function onStage(e:Event) {
                    trace('Scroller.as: on stage');
                stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, handleScrollbarMouse); 
                stage.addEventListener(Event.MOUSE_LEAVE, handleLeave);  }, false, 0, true);

        }
        else{
            vscrollbar_mc.visible = false;
            hscrollbar_mc.visible = false;
        }

        if (!isScroll)
        {
            vscrollbar_mc.visible = false;
            hscrollbar_mc.visible = false;
        }
        if (isScroll)
        {
            addChild(bg);
            createMask();
            bg.cacheAsBitmap = true;
            source.cacheAsBitmap = true;
            source.mask = bg;
            vscrollbar_mc.alpha = 1;
            hscrollbar_mc.alpha = 1;
        }


        //choose between mouse move and enter frame ghandling
        if ((dir=="ver" && source.height > ph) || (dir=="hor" && source.width > pw)){
        addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, handleMouse);
        addEventListener(Event.REMOVED_FROM_STAGE, handleRemove);
        }

    }
    public function handleMouse(e:Event){
        //trace(mouseDown);
        //the function which moves the source depending on mouse
        if (scrollbar == "on")
        {
        if (mouseDown == true)
        {

            if (dir == "ver")
            {
            scrollIndex = scrollbar_mc.mouseY - (scrollbar_mc.head_mc.height >> 1);

            if (scrollIndex < 0) scrollIndex = 0;
            if (scrollIndex > h - scrollbar_mc.head_mc.height) scrollIndex = h - scrollbar_mc.head_mc.height;
            Tweener.addTween(scrollbar_mc.head_mc, { y:scrollIndex, time:0.5 } );
            Tweener.addTween(scrollbar_mc.head_mc, { _frame:30, time:1 } );


            viewIndex = (scrollIndex / (h - scrollbar_mc.head_mc.height)) * -(source.height - h);
            Tweener.addTween(source, { y:viewIndex, rounded:true, time:1 } );

            if (blurScroll == "on")
            Tweener.addTween(source, { _Blur_blurY:Math.abs(viewIndex-source.y)/5, time:0.3 } );

            }
            else
            {
                scrollIndex = scrollbar_mc.mouseX - (scrollbar_mc.head_mc.width>>1);
                if (scrollIndex < 0) scrollIndex = 0;
                if (scrollIndex > w - scrollbar_mc.head_mc.width) scrollIndex = w - scrollbar_mc.head_mc.width;
                Tweener.addTween(scrollbar_mc.head_mc, { x:scrollIndex, time:0.5 } );
                Tweener.addTween(scrollbar_mc.head_mc, { _frame:30, time:1 } );


                viewIndex = (scrollIndex / (w - scrollbar_mc.head_mc.width)) * -(source.width - w);
                Tweener.addTween(source, { x:viewIndex, time:1 } );

                if (blurScroll == "on")
                {
                    Tweener.addTween(source, { _Blur_blurX:Math.abs(viewIndex-source.x)/5, time:0.3 } );

                }
            }

        }
        }
        else
        {
        if (mouseY > 0 && mouseY < h && mouseX > 0 && mouseX < w)
        {
        if (dir == "ver")
        {
        viewIndex = (mouseY / h) * -(source.height - h + errorOffset * 2 + scrollOffset * 2) + scrollOffset + errorOffset;
        if (viewIndex > scrollOffset) viewIndex = scrollOffset;
        if (viewIndex < -(source.height-h-1 + scrollOffset)) viewIndex = -(source.height-h-1 + scrollOffset);

        Tweener.addTween(source, { y:viewIndex, transition:"easeOutSine", rounded:true, time:.3 } );

        //set up blur scrolling
        if (blurScroll == "on")
        {
            Tweener.addTween(source, { _Blur_blurY:Math.abs(viewIndex-source.y)/5, time:.2 } );

        }
        }
        else
        {

            viewIndex = (mouseX / w) * -(source.width - w + errorOffset * 2 + scrollOffset * 2) + scrollOffset + errorOffset;
            if (viewIndex > scrollOffset) viewIndex = scrollOffset;
            if (viewIndex < -(source.width-w + scrollOffset)) viewIndex = -(source.width-w + scrollOffset);

            Tweener.addTween(source, { x:viewIndex, transition:"easeOutSine", rounded:true, time:.3 } );

            //set up blur scrolling
            if (blurScroll == "on")
            {
                Tweener.addTween(source, { _Blur_blurX:Math.abs(viewIndex-source.x)/5, time:.2 } );

            }
        }

        }
        else
        {
            Tweener.addTween(source, { _Blur_blurY:0,_Blur_blurX:0, time:.2 } );
        }
        }
    }
    public function handleRemove(e:Event)
    {
        if(hasEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME))
        removeEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, handleMouse);

        if(hasEventListener(Event.REMOVED_FROM_STAGE))
        removeEventListener(Event.REMOVED_FROM_STAGE, handleRemove);

        if(hasEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_WHEEL))
        removeEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_WHEEL, handleMouseWheel);

    }
    public function handleScrollbarMouse(e:MouseEvent)
    {
        //function which gets the scrollbars attention
        if (e.type == "mouseDown")
        {
            mouseDown = true;

        }
        if (e.type == "mouseUp")
        {

            mouseDown = false;
            if(scrollbar_mc!=null)
            Tweener.addTween(scrollbar_mc.head_mc, { _frame:1, time:1 } );
            if(blurScroll=="on")
            Tweener.addTween(source, { _Blur_blurY:0,_Blur_blurX:0, time:.2 } );

        }
    }
    public function handleMouseWheel(e:MouseEvent)
    {
        //mouse wheel function 
        scrollIndex -= e.delta;
            if (scrollIndex < 0) scrollIndex = 0;
            if (scrollIndex > h - scrollbar_mc.head_mc.height) scrollIndex = h - scrollbar_mc.head_mc.height;
            Tweener.addTween(scrollbar_mc.head_mc, { y:scrollIndex, time:0.5 } );


            viewIndex = (scrollIndex / (h - scrollbar_mc.head_mc.height)) * -(source.height - h);
            Tweener.addTween(source, { y:viewIndex, time:1 } );
    }
    public function handleLeave(e:Event)
    {
        trace('Scroller.as: left stage');
        mouseDown = false;
        if(scrollbar_mc!=null)
        Tweener.addTween(scrollbar_mc.head_mc, { _frame:1, time:1 } );
        Tweener.addTween(source, { _Blur_blurY:0,_Blur_blurX:0, time:.2 } );
    }
    public function createMask()
    {
        var bgmain:Sprite = new Sprite();

        if (gradientMask != "on")
        {

            bgmain.graphics.beginFill(0x000000);
            bgmain.graphics.drawRect(0, 0, w, h);
            bg.addChild(bgmain);
        }
        else
        {
            var bgup:Sprite = new Sprite();
            var bgdown:Sprite = new Sprite();
            var matrix:Matrix= new Matrix();
            var colors:Array=[0x000000,0x000000];
            var alphas:Array=[0,1];
            var ratios:Array=[0,255];
            matrix.createGradientBox(maskSize,w);

            if (dir == "ver")
            {
                bgup.graphics.lineStyle();
                bgup.graphics.beginGradientFill(GradientType.LINEAR,colors,alphas,ratios,matrix);
                bgup.graphics.drawRect(0,0,maskSize,w);
                bgup.graphics.endFill();
                bgup.rotation = 90;
                bgup.x = w;
                bg.addChild(bgup);
                bgmain.graphics.beginFill(0x000000);
                bgmain.graphics.drawRect(0, 0, w, h - maskSize * 2);
                bgmain.y = maskSize;
                bg.addChild(bgmain);
                alphas = [1, 0];
                bgdown.graphics.lineStyle();
                bgdown.graphics.beginGradientFill(GradientType.LINEAR,colors,alphas,ratios,matrix);
                bgdown.graphics.drawRect(0,0,maskSize,w);
                bgdown.graphics.endFill();
                bgdown.rotation = 90;
                bgdown.x = w;
                bgdown.y = h - maskSize;
                bg.addChild(bgdown);
            }
            else
            {
                bgup.graphics.lineStyle();
                bgup.graphics.beginGradientFill(GradientType.LINEAR,colors,alphas,ratios,matrix);
                bgup.graphics.drawRect(0,0,maskSize,h);
                bgup.graphics.endFill();
                //bgup.rotation = 90;
                //bgup.x = maskSize;
                bg.addChild(bgup);
                bgmain.graphics.beginFill(0x000000);
                bgmain.graphics.drawRect(0, 0, w - maskSize * 2, h);
                bgmain.x = maskSize;
                bg.addChild(bgmain);
                alphas = [1, 0];
                bgdown.graphics.lineStyle();
                bgdown.graphics.beginGradientFill(GradientType.LINEAR,colors,alphas,ratios,matrix);
                bgdown.graphics.drawRect(0,0,maskSize,h);
                bgdown.graphics.endFill();
                //bgdown.rotation = 90;
                bgdown.x = w - maskSize;
                //bgdown.y = h - maskSize;
                bg.addChild(bgdown);
            }
        }
    }



}
   }
```

Comment: See [writing the perfect question](http://msmvps.com/blogs/jon_skeet/archive/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question.aspx)

Comment: Did you write this code? If no, what do you understand of it? Can you provide an example of what you have now and be more specific about what you are trying to get?

Answer (score 0):

I do not understand exactly what you want to achive but the reason the speed (time) won't change with the fps is that you (or the one that wrote the code) uses Tweener to control the animation. But my suggestions are:

- Try changing the time values (higher numbers = slower animations)
- If you want to affect all the timings try any of this in the constructor:

  //half speed

  Tweener.setTimeScale(.5);

  OR

  //double speed

  Tweener.setTimeScale(2);